# What is the best way to process large arrays without hitting memory requirements in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got two arrays of strings, both with 250k+ items. When I tried to hardcode these into my C++ program, it got stuck in the compilation phase. I currently have both strings as CSV .txt files e.g., {..."fksdfjsa", "fsdajhfisa","wgferwjhgo"...}.

Should I save these as arrays in a different C++ program and try to import them, or should I somehow stream them as I iterate through the values? If so, how would I do that? For what it's worth, I intend to compare each element of the first array to each element of the second.

Comment: I apologize in advance for the lack of direction -- I'm new to both C++ and large file IO and don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: If the constant data won't fit into the code space, place into a file.

Comment: Nothing to do with "processing" since it (apparently) won't even compile.. make sure the title accurately reflects the problem.

Comment: I would be tempted to read the smaller file into memory in a `std::vector` and then read in the larger one, one string at a time, comparing it to every element of the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the data from your CSV files at runtime. Learn about the `<fstream>` standard library header.

Answer (score 0):

Read data  using [std::fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) and use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead creating array

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly read the input from files.  Among other things: you can start debugging/testing on smaller input files.

If you google for C++ CSV readers you can probably save yourself the time of debugging your own.

Finally: the goal of this exercise isn't described, but "...compare each element..." done naively is going to take a long time.  If you are looking for matches: consider sorting the inputs first and running through the lists in parallel.  This will bring it back to linear time.

Comment: linear for the comparison, but still O(n*logn) since you have to sort them first, definitely better than the O(n^2) proposed here though.